# defining sort method in Ruby using recursion?

Tags: ruby, sorting, recursion

I'm working on LTP by Chris Pine, ch 10 - trying to create my own sort method using recursion. I've done it without recursion, but I can't figure out why this recursive method doesn't work. It returns an empty array & then two "nil" arrays.

```
words = ["this", "that", "Patrick", "Svetlana", "USA", "aviation", "that"]

def sort_r(array, sorted_array=[])
  sorted_array.push(array.min)

  if array != []
    array.delete_at(array.index(array.min))
    sort_r(array, sorted_array)
  end

  p sorted_array
end

p sort_r(words)
```

Comment: I get `["Patrick", "Svetlana", "USA", "aviation", "that", "that", "this", nil]` - please share your expected output and actual output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nil` gets added at the end of result in last iteration of recursion by as `array` is `[]` in that case, and you push an `min` from empty array into `sorted_array` in first line of your function.

You need to check `if array != []` after removing the `min` from the `array` and avoid calling the recursive method if its `[]`

---

Your code can be simplified to below:

```
words = ["this", "that", "Patrick", "Svetlana", "USA", "aviation", "that"]

def sort_r(array, sorted_array=[])
  sorted_array << array.delete_at(array.index(array.min))
  sort_r(array, sorted_array) unless array.size.zero?
  sorted_array
end

p sort_r(words)
#=> ["Patrick", "Svetlana", "USA", "aviation", "that", "that", "this"]
```